# Нормы передачи на письме смеха

Tags: стилистика

Я всегда знал, что смех на письме передается "ха-ха-ха", но сейчас в интернете все чаще встречаются какие-то ахи ("ахаха"). Само собой, это стадное чувство и неумение думать своей головой. Но есть ли какая-то литературная норма для обозначения смеха?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Вы о чём? Какая норма в Интернете? Здесь полное творчество. В русском языке общеприняты звукоподражания для передачи громкого смеха ха-ха-ха, тихого сдержанного хи-хи-хи.

А в Интернете всякое встретишь: Хаааааааааааахахаха, ууу. 
Но есть и общепринятые обозначения:  LOL. Или :-). Или «ha».

А если  шутка — веселее и смешнее, чем обычно, то это будет «ha ha». А если не очень смешная, то «hе». А если там будет ирония, то «hе hе». А если шутка будет ну очень смешной и озорной, требующей дополнительного хохота, то ответ будет такой: «hahaha». Или «haaaaahaha». Или даже «haaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaahaha»

Comment: А ещё :D, и даже :Д.